# What's the name property of function object?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    function obj1(){}
    alert(obj1.name);

    var obj2 = function(){}
    obj2.name = 'obj2';
    alert(obj2.name=='');

</script>
```

I have tested the code in Chrome, ff, safari

But IE9 don't have this property .

question is where I can read documents to find all this kind of situations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mozilla documentation says this:

```
name
  Non-standard 
  The name of the function.
```

So, it's a non-standard feature that is implemented by some browsers. As there is no standard to dictate how it should work, the implementation is likely to differ between browsers.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

The [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com) and [Mozilla](http://developer.mozilla.org) documentations are pretty complete, and you will find any standard feature in either of them. If you find a non-standard property like this, it will typically be documented only for the browser that does support it.

---

The definitive resource for the Javascript language is of course the [EcmaScript ECMA-262 standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), however it's a lot more complicated to read than the documentation for the implementations.

For a feature in the DOM (HTML, CSS, Javscript interface), it's the [W3C organisation](http://www.w3c.org) that specifies the standards.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Microsoft specs here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x844tc74%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

But indeed, it is non-standard, and MS chose to follow the spec this time.

Answer (score 0):

Functions created with the syntax new Function(...) or just Function(...) have their name property set to "anonymous" on Firefox and Safari, or to an empty string on Chrome and Opera. This property is not supported on Internet Explorer.

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Name